# Two OO questions reg constructors

Tags: java, oop

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal() {
        this("Animal->Horse");
        System.out.println("Class Animal default const");
    }

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
    String name;
}

public class Pegasus extends Animal {
        public Pegasus() {
        System.out.println("Class Pegasus default const");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal("Black Horse");
        animal.name = "Pegasus";
        Pegasus pegasus = new Pegasus();
        pegasus.name = "White Horse";
    }
}
```

When I execute this I get:

```
Black Horse
Animal->Horse
Class Animal default const
Class Pegasus default const
```

**Q1:** Why does `Animal->Horse` get printed only once when `animal` instance is created and not when `pegasus` instance is created? Essentially its called from the default constructor. Also why doesn't `animal` instance print `Class Animal default const`?

**Q2:** When I create the `pegasus` instance, is there a way for it not to call `class Animal`'s default constructor and just call `class Pegasus` default constructor?

Comment: Why are you printing out "Animal->Horse" in your Animal constructor? It implies that you are creating a Horse as the default animal, which may or may not be the intention. In any case, a class called "Animal" should be abstract, because any when someone asks you "what is an animal?" you can (probably will) answer it with "it depends what kind of animal it is".

Comment: @ArnabDatta: Thanks :) but that was just to print something. But I do get the point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Q1: Why does Animal->Horse get printed only once when animal instance is created and not when pegasus instance is created?

It's the other way round - it's *not* being printed when you call the `Animal(String)` constructor with `new Animal("Black Horse")`, but it *is* being printed when you call the `Pegasus()` constructor which in turn calls the `Animal()` constructor which in turn calls the `Animal(String)` constructor.

I strongly suggest that you put an extra line of diagnostic text *after* the `new Animal("Black Horse")` constructor call. That will help you to see what's going on more clearly.

> Q2: When I create the pegasus instance, is there a way for it not to call class Animal's default constructor

Well it could call the `Animal(String)` constructor e.g. with

```
super("Pegasus");
```

but it has to call *some* constructor in `Animal`. When you create an instance of a class, *all* the classes in its inheritance hierarchy have to be initialized via at least one constructor in each class.

Comment: Aah, I get it. But if a superclass does not have any implementation of a constructor then what does the derived class call on its own? Is it the default constructor? But what is the purpose?

Comment: There is an implied no-arg constructor defined for every class that does not explicitly define one.

Comment: Just to clarify, a default constructor is created for every class that does not explicitly declare *any* constructors. If you specify a constructor with a parameter, the compiler *doesn't* also create a parameterless one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: both constructors have "equal billing", and so there is no need for the 1-arg method to also invoke the no-arg constructor. So the only ctor to be invoked is the 1-arg, which gives you the first line of your output.

Q2: your Pegasus is an instance of Animal, so before it can begin to initialize the Pegasus portion, it must first initialize the Animal portion. To do so it needs to choose an animal constructor.  Since you do not explicitly call one it chooses the "default" version, i.e. the no-arg one. The no arg-one first calls the one-arg one and gives you the 2nd line of output. Then the no-arg one continues with your 3rd output line. Finally, your Pegasus ctor can now be invoked, resulting in your 4th line.